# How implement query which scrape metric only from currently live pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a quite common scenario where a pod was just redeployed and so given a metric I see both from dead pod and new one.

Now I would like to implement an alert just for example about the number of busy thread in the tomcat thread pool, so I want that metric from the only up and running pod, I have no label to distinguish the two pods, the previously running and the currently running.

What could I use in a prometheus query to get a metric only from the currently running pod?

Comment: Alert rules are evaluated on the "current" values (read about [staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness)). So usually, dead pods are not problem for rules if they died more that 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

The below commands describe whether the pod is ready to serve the requests.

**`sum(kube_pod_status_ready{condition="true"}) by (namespace, pod)`**

This node selects the latest (non-stale) sample value within the last 5 minutes for any series that match all of the following criteria:

- The metric name is **kube_pod_status_ready**.
- condition="**true**": The label condition is exactly "true".

Try the above command which has a label as **true** which means it can eliminate the dead pod, If this doesn’t work, try the below command which does not have any label constraints.

**`sum(kube_pod_status_ready) by (namespace, pod)`**

This node selects the latest (non-stale) sample value within the last 5 minutes for any series that match all of the following criteria:

- The metric name is **kube_pod_status_ready**.

You can refer to the **[github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/main/docs/pod-metrics.md)** link for more information.